Dash Plotly Visualization
I'm trying to use dropdowns to select columns of my data frame to put them into the plot. Currently, the x and y are static, the dropdowns can update the column names, but I cannot update the graph itself to reflect the data inside the column.
I've tried setting the px.scatter y parameter to filtered_df[ "yaxis_column_name"] but since there is no real error output, it's hard for me to adjust the syntax, I've also tried calling an object to represent a data column (i.e. pnty) to put in place, which runs but still doesn't update the graph.
    from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
    import plotly.express as px

    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RouseJo/DTSC691/main/Full.csv")

    app = Dash(__name__)

    app.layout = html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            df.columns,
            'Columns',
            id='xaxis-column'
        ),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            df.columns,
            'Columns',
            id='yaxis-column'
        ),
        dcc.Graph(id='graph-with-slider'),
        dcc.Slider(
            df['yr'].min(),
            df['yr'].max(),
            step=None,
            value=df['yr'].min(),
            marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df['yr'].unique()},
            id='year-slider'
        )
    
    ])


    @callback(
        Output('graph-with-slider', 'figure'),
        Input('year-slider', 'value'),
        Input('xaxis-column', 'value'),
        Input('yaxis-column', 'value')
    )
    def update_figure(selected_year, xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name):
        filtered_df = df[df['yr'] == selected_year]
        pntx = print(xaxis_column_name)

        pnty = print(yaxis_column_name)

        fig = px.scatter(df, x="TMP", y="SPFH",
                     size="wid", color="len", hover_name="SPFH",
                     log_x=True, size_max=55)

        fig.update_yaxes(title=yaxis_column_name,
                     type='linear')

        fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)

        return fig


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)



you need a datatable element which will be modified by the dropdowns. Start reading the dash quickstart here: https://dash.plotly.com/tutorial there is also a chapter "connecting to data"

I believe the source of your issue is function argument mismatch. A good practice is to specify the argument rather than use positional arguments (e.g. px.scatter([1,2,3], [4,5,6]) vs. pc.scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[4,5,6]).
"Columns" was being set as the value in each dropdown, even though it is not a column in the data frame.

Somewhat Confusing Note on dcc.Dropdown's value attribute: the value can break rules set by the input as shown to the user.
In this particular example, the value of both dropdowns were set to "Columns" even though it was not a valid option in df.columns. Even though the dropdown does not display "Column" as selected, under the hood it will still be used.

I would highly suggest going through dash's tutorials (https://dash.plotly.com/tutorial) as mastering details like these will be essential to becoming a successful dash app developer.
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, Input, Output, callback, dcc, html

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RouseJo/DTSC691/main/Full.csv")

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Dropdown(options=df.columns, id="xaxis-column"),
        dcc.Dropdown(options=df.columns, id="yaxis-column"),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph-with-slider"),
        dcc.Slider(
            df["yr"].min(),
            df["yr"].max(),
            step=None,
            value=df["yr"].min(),
            marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df["yr"].unique()},
            id="year-slider",
        ),
    ]
)


@callback(
    Output("graph-with-slider", "figure"),
    Input("year-slider", "value"),
    Input("xaxis-column", "value"),
    Input("yaxis-column", "value"),
)
def update_figure(selected_year, xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name):
    filtered_df = df[df["yr"] == selected_year]
    fig = px.scatter(
        filtered_df,
        x=xaxis_column_name,
        y=yaxis_column_name,
        size="wid",
        color="len",
        hover_name="SPFH",
        log_x=True,
        size_max=55,
    )

    fig.update_yaxes(title=yaxis_column_name, type="linear")

    fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)

    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

